# angular directive (ng-class) inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just would like to show and hide an spinner every time that a user click on the link, in this case I'm using a promise to wrap the actual click method, when the promise get resolved I want hide the spinner.

for some reason it seems like the directive isn't binding the value that I have in the scope with the ng-class in the template

any ideas?

```
   app.directive('toogleTextLink', function($compile,$q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { callback: "&targetMethod" },
        template: '<div><a style="cursor: pointer" ><b>{{text}}</b></a> <div ng-class="{previewLoader: show}"></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.value = attr.value;
            scope.show = false;
            scope.$watch('value', function () {
                    if (scope.value) {
                        scope.text = "yes";
                    } else {
                        scope.text = "no";
                    }
            });
            element.bind('click', function () {
                scope.show = true;
                scope.value = !scope.value;
                scope.$apply();
                if (scope.callback) {

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(scope.callback());
                    deferred.promise.then(function () {
                        scope.show = false;
                        console.log("then called");
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

take a look to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1ocIp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seams the size of the spinner (CSS) also you are resolving the promise immediately, so you wont be able to see the spinner.

Check these changes
http://plnkr.co/edit/viwzCb?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the answer, in fact the css was part of the issue (working until late night isn´t good), so I have updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EZjCIo?p=preview and what I waant to do is to wait until my callback finish the execution and then hide the spinner

Comment: check this simplified plunker, for an example of waiting a promise http://plnkr.co/edit/TwZoJB?p=preview

Comment: I have created another question about difering a method execution inside a directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818472/how-to-defer-a-method-execution-in-a-directive-in-angularjs